# Keyless fob and radio dead on Pontiac Vibe 2005

Tags: audio, pontiac, keyless-entry, fob, vibe

Today I went out to my 2005 Pontiac Vibe and the keyless fob wasn't working at all (none of the buttons and my wife's wasn't working either so it's not the battery of the fob) and the radio unit was completely dead.  The cigarette lighter works and I think that the outlet works.  The lights on the underside of the front mirror are also not working but I haven't used them in a while to know if it happened earlier.  Everything else seems to be working fine.

Do you know what the issue is and how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: I think it could be as simple as a blown fuse, specifically the one that powers the Body Control Module "BCM" in GM cars.  Your owner's manual should give you guidance as to which fuses to check.  Search for Accessory, Radio

Comment: I think @SteveRacer is spot on. Check the fuses.

Comment: It was the fuse for the dome in the engine fuse box. It looks like something is short circuited since when I tried replacing the fuse, there is an electrical spark and the new fuse blew. Is there anything I can do about this myself or do I need a mechanic?